# How to use StreamPlot to plot the typical solution in this directional field?

Tags: plotting, homework

How can I plot the typical solution in this directional field using `StreamPlot`?

[image: The equation is:]

```
f[x_, y_] := y - y^3
p1 = StreamPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, BaseStyle -> 12, 
  StreamPoints -> {{{{-1, 0}, Red}, Automatic}}]
```

I want to plot the typical solution, for example, when -1<y<0 and y<-1.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this?

```
f[x_, y_] := y - y^3
p1 = StreamPlot[
  {1, f[x, y]},
  {x, -3, 3},
  {y, -3, 3},
  Frame -> False,
  Axes -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"},
  BaseStyle -> 12,
  StreamPoints -> {{
     {{-1, 0}, Red},
     {{-1, -3}, Green},      (* Only this line and the next are changed. *)
     {{-1, -1/2}, Orange},
     Automatic
    }}
 ]
```

[image: StreamPlot with highligthed flow lines]

Answer (score 2):

Here is something taken from code I wrote many years ago. It works only for autonomous first-order ODEs, but it gives an alternative approach to the OP's example.

```
ClearAll[dfPortrait];
dfPortrait[vf_, {fn_, x1_, x2_}, {time_, t1_, t2_}, opts___?OptionQ] :=
    Module[{stationaryPts, intervals, eqns, x0}
   , plotrange = {All, {x1, x2}}
   ; padding = {0.1, (x2 - x1) {0.03, 0.02}}
   ; stationaryPts = 
    fn /. Solve[vf == 0 && x1 <= fn <= x2, fn, Reals] /. fn -> {}
   ; intervals = Partition[Union[N@{x1, x2}, N@stationaryPts], 2, 1]
   ; eqns = {Derivative[1][fn][time] == (vf /. fn -> fn[time]), 
     fn[0] == x0}
   ; With[{psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns
       , fn, {time, t1, t2}, {x0}
       , "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
         "WarningMessage" -> False}
       ]}
    , Plot[
     Evaluate[Quiet[(psol[#1][time] &) /@
        Join[stationaryPts
         , If[(vf /. fn -> Mean[#1]) > 0
            , {0.9, 0.1}.#1
            , {0.1, 0.9}.#1
            ] & /@ intervals
         ]]]
     , {time, t1, t2}
     , PlotRange -> plotrange, PlotRangePadding -> padding , 
     ImageSize -> {Automatic, 150}, Ticks -> {None, stationaryPts}, 
     ExclusionsStyle -> None, AxesLabel -> {time, fn /. x_[0] :> x}
     ]]
   ];

dfPortrait[y - y^3, {y, -2, 2}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

I used it to illustrate autonomous first-order ODEs with figures like the following, where the `v` denotes the derivative ("velocity"), and the middle graph is the phase field on the line; this type diagram can be seen in V.I. Arnold's *Ordinary Differential Equations*.

[image]

Comment: It is really very illustrative. I appreciate it a lot. But my goal was to make it look a bit like this: 1.[link](https://imgur.com/OsXcIDA)2.[link](https://imgur.com/tqZMoFw), to help to select the correct answer. Thank u, Michael!

Comment: @MichaelE2: How did you draw the last figure?

Comment: @Moo It's an old function I wrote many years ago.  The code needs refactoring, which I started yesterday but my stupid compute crashed unexpectedly (not due to *Mma* either) and lost the work.  The function is called `portrait1D` and is contained in the old package, which I uploaded here: https://pastebin.com/raw/ra8sftKY

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks and I would love to see those updates! +1